# Hammer.js jQUery plugin does not work in IE7/8

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins, internet-explorer-8, hammer.js

Hammer.js Compatible table says that jquery.hammer.js works corretly in IE7/8. But I have got an error

```
"Object does not support this property or method"
(method "addEventListener" in "element")    
Hammer.utils.each(types, function(type){
    element.addEventListener(type, handler, false);
});
```

I use next version of Hammer.js jQUery plugin:

```
/*! jQuery plugin for Hammer.JS - v1.0.0 - 2014-01-02
 * http://eightmedia.github.com/hammer.js
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2014 Jorik Tangelder <j.tangelder@gmail.com>;
 * Licensed under the MIT license *//*! Hammer.JS - v1.0.6 - 2014-01-02
 * http://eightmedia.github.com/hammer.js
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2014 Jorik Tangelder <j.tangelder@gmail.com>;
 * Licensed under the MIT license */
```

Answer (score 0):

The current version of Hammer.js (v2.0.4) does not support Internet Explorer 8.

Full browser/device support can be found here:

http://hammerjs.github.io/browser-support/